# Find and copying text highlighted in a specific color

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

Hi I have a code (see below) that is working like a charm to find and copy text from a specific style and paste it in another document. It is in an excel file because I preferred this option to share with friends that would only need to click in the button, chose the input file and save as their preferred output file name.

Now I'm trying without success to perform the same task with text highlighted in a specific color (e. Turquoise). Please find below the code that is working with a specific word or style, I made some experiences with code I found here and there, but all I could get was to copy all highlighted text instead of my choice of color. See below.  Any help is much appreciated.

Note on Edit: The code below is the closer I get to the desired result. It was a little chaotic due to my try and error attempts.

```
       
   ' Objects
    Dim wrdApp, objWord As Object
    Dim wrdDoc, newwrdDoc As Object
    Dim myPath As String, myPath1 As String
    Dim folderPath As String
    Dim myFile As String
    Dim numberStart As Long
    Dim Rng, srchRng As Excel.Range
    
    'Dim objDoc As Document, objDocAdd As Document
    Dim objRange As Range
    Dim strFindColor As String
    Dim highliteColor As Variant
    Dim i As Long
    
   ' Close MS Word if it's already opened
    On Error Resume Next
     Set objWord = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
     If Not objWord Is Nothing Then
            objWord.Quit SaveChanges:=0
            Set objWord = Nothing
    End If
    'Defining input file name
    myFile = Application.GetOpenFilename()
    
    'Open MS Word
    Set wrdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
        wrdApp.Visible = True
        
    ' Folder Location
    myPath = Application.ThisWorkbook.Path & "\"
    
    ' Input File
    Set wrdDoc = wrdApp.Documents.Open(myFile)
    
    ' Output File
    Set newwrdDoc = wrdApp.Documents.Add
    myPath1 = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(FileFilter:="Word files(*.docx),*.docx")
    
    ' Text you want to search
    'Dim FindWord As String
    'Dim result As String
    'FindWord = ""
    highliteColor = Array(wdTurquoise)
    
    'Style
    'mystyle = wdTurquoise
    
    'Defines selection for Word's find function
    wrdDoc.SelectAllEditableRanges
    
    ' Find Functionality in MS Word
    For i = LBound(wdTurquoise) To UBound(wdTurquoise)
        objDoc.Activate
        Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdStory
        objRange.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
      With wrdDoc.ActiveWindow.Selection.Find
            .HighlightColorIndex = wdTurquoise
            .Highlight = True
            .Forward = True
            .Wrap = wdFindStop
           objRange = Selection.Range
           objDocAdd.Range.InsertAfter objRange & vbCr
           Selection.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
                    
      End With
    Next
                 
    ' Execute find method
    wrdDoc.ActiveWindow.Selection.Find.Execute
    
    ' Store Selected text
    result = wrdDoc.ActiveWindow.Selection.Text
    
    ' Check if result contains non-blank text
    If Len(result) > 1 Then
    
    ' -------------------------------------------------------------
    ' Loop through multiple find content (Find All functionality)
    ' -------------------------------------------------------------

  While wrdDoc.ActiveWindow.Selection.Find.Found
    wrdDoc.ActiveWindow.Selection.Copy
      
    'Activate the new document
    newwrdDoc.Activate
    
    'New Word Doc
    Set Rng = newwrdDoc.Content
    Rng.Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd
    Rng.Paste
   
   'Word Document
   wrdDoc.Activate
   wrdDoc.ActiveWindow.Selection.Find.Execute
   
 Wend
   
   ' If style not found
    Else
        MsgBox "Text Not Found"
    End If
   
    'Close and don't save application
    wrdDoc.Close SaveChanges:=False
    
    'Save As New Word Document
    newwrdDoc.SaveAs myPath1
    newwrdDoc.Close SaveChanges:=True
    
    'Close all word documents
    wrdApp.Quit SaveChanges:=0
    
    'Message when done
    MsgBox "Task Accomplished"
End Sub
```

Comment: `.HighlightColorIndex = wdTurquoise` maybe ?

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad , I tried with `.HighLight=True`  and a condition in the if found only copy if  `.HighlightColorIndex = wdTurquoise` , but in my tests it either copied all highlights or nothing.

Comment: We can only help you debug your code if you post the code that you are actually using. Please use the [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70758068/edit) link below the question and add your code.

Comment: @TimothyRylatt Ok, I just edited with the closest I got to the desired results. It copies all the highlights and not just Turquoise. It was so chaotic that I pasted the original code before.

Comment: Your first major issue is that you have used `On Error Resume Next`, so all the errors in your code, and there are quite a few, are being suppressed. Reset the error handling by adding `On Error GoTo 0`  after the block of code where you close Word if already open. You will then be able to see where the errors are in your code and begin fixing them. You should also add a reference to the Word object library and declare your variables correctly instead of declaring them as `Object`. This will enable you to use Intellisense to get the syntax correct.

Comment: Thanks @TimothyRylatt. I will try some options, although my limited ability (I took this code from different examples I found here and in other sites) I will make an effort to debug by myself.